# Store strings of the same length in contiguous memory?

Tags: c++, c++11

How do you store strings of the same length (the number of strings may vary, but each string has the same length) in contiguous memory?
Is it possible?

Comment: Are these constant strings or will you be modifying them as the program runs?

Comment: Sounds like a [X-Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), what exactly do you want to solve?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. It will be helpful to provide more context.

Comment: Did you try using an object of type `std::vector<std::string>` to store your strings?  Was there something wrong with it?

Comment: @DavidGrayson, I just came up this problem in my mind when I was reading about the [scoped alocator](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2008/n2554.pdf)

Comment: Instead of using `std::string`, use `std::basic_string<char, ...>` and then you can use any allocator you like.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest way is probably, don't use `std::string`, use `std::array<char, N>` for the strings (where `N` is the common length, and maybe replace `char` with `wchar` if necessary) and then put those in a `std::vector`:

```
typedef std::array<char, N> string_type;
typedef std::vector<string_type> contiguous_strings;
```

If the length `N` is not known at compile-time (or if an upper bound is not known) then you'll have to do something more complicated. I guess you'd want to use boost flat containers.

Answer (score 0):

Use vector of array. If you know the length of each string.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution maybe,

```
class String: public std::string
{
public:
    String(): std::string(SIZE_OF_STRING, DEFAULT_CHAR){}
};
```

And using something like,

```
std::vector< String > v;
```

This lets you to use the features provided by std::string as well.

You can override other std::string constructors where necessary.

Comment: probably wont work, since `std::string` use heap-allocated buffers.

Answer (score 0):

The question leaves a lot to the imagination.  Not saying it's a great general solution, but for the sake of listing yet another alternative - using a single `std::string()` that contains a concatenatation of the textual strings may be workable.  You can store ASCII NUL characters, so `(my_string.data() + N * i)`, where N is the shared length including the NUL, gives a `const char*` to the (i+1)th contained string: you can use that `const char*` to call functions written for ASCIIZ C-style strings, including the `std::string(const char*)` constructor if you need an independent object.  Of course the `std::string` itself won't necessarily be contiguously allocated alongside the text it controls, much as is the case for a pointer to a dynamically allocated buffer.